# Icon vertical alignment in Bootstrap 2.3.2 navbar-form

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a Bootstrap 2.3.2 project where there's a navigation bar. This bar contains icons (Fontawesome) that are just icons (not a button or a link). However, these are incorrectly vertically aligned. They stick to the top.

Here's a dumbed down example:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="navbar-form pull-left">
      <i class="icon-time"></i>
      <button class="btn">
        Some button
      </button>
      <select>
        <option>Option 1</option>
        <option>Option 2</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to move the clock icon in the above example down, so it aligns with the text on the same line. Preferably by just using Twitter Bootstrap classes, but I can't find anything in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe add vertical-align?

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<style>
    .icon-time { 
        vertical-align: -6px;
}

</style>
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="navbar-form pull-left">
      <i class="icon-time"></i>
      <button class="btn">
        Some button
      </button>
      <select>
        <option>Option 1</option>
        <option>Option 2</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sure, that works, but it's a bit ad-hoc. I was wondering if there was a bootstrap-way? If not, I could generalize this into a custom css rule of course. Also, didn't know you could use units in `vertical-align`, nice.

Comment: Not sure that bootstrap has something specific for vertical align. You may do the same with margin-top instead.